# How to exclude files and folders from Get-ChildItem in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, get-filehash

I've made a PowerShell script that runs robocopy with md5 checks.

It works fine, but if I try to exclude some dirs or files, robocopy handles the exclusion, whereas MD5 part of script that compares the hash, doesn't work, returns some errors because the source has more files/hash than destination...

I've tried, maybe, all methods that I've found here and on the Internet! I can't exclude dirs and/or files from a path!

Below is what I've done so far. In this mode, the md5-copy works (without exclusions):

```
$Source = "F:\"

$IgnoreDir = @(
    $Source + '$RECYCLE.BIN'
    $Source + "System Volume Information"
    $Source + "VMs"
)   
$IgnoreFile = @(
    $Source + "SHDrive.vmdk"
    $Source + "SHDrive-flat.vmdk"
)
$Ignored = $IgnoreDir + $IgnoreFile
```

Robocopy:

```
Robocopy.exe /R:1 /W:0 $Source $Dest /E /V /TEE /XD $IgnoreDir /XF $IgnoreFile /LOG:$LogDir\RBCY_MD5_F.txt
```

MD5:

```
$SourceHash = Get-ChildItem "$Source\*.*" -Recurse -Force -Exclude $Ignored | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | Get-FileHash
$SourceHash | Select-Object "Hash", "path" | ft -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize | Out-File -Width "300" $LogDir\SRC_MD5_REF.txt
$SourceHash.Hash | Out-File $LogDir\SRC_MD5.txt
```

Comparing:

```
$Diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(get-content "$LogDir\SRC_MD5.txt") -DifferenceObject $(get-content "$LogDir\DST_MD5.txt")
```

Content of F:\ drive:

```
PS C:\Users\Robbi> Get-ChildItem F:\ -force


    Directory: F:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d--hs-       19/03/2019     06:40                $RECYCLE.BIN
d-----       16/05/2020     04:41                DATA
d-----       19/01/2020     06:34                Drivers
d-----       16/05/2020     04:55                Gumball
d-----       16/05/2020     04:58                SW
d--hs-       19/03/2019     06:36                System Volume Information
d-----       13/03/2020     16:08                Tools
d-----       12/12/2019     00:02                VMs
d-----       16/05/2020     04:55                _Pre-Cestino
-a----       08/02/2020     03:02    21474836480 SHDrive-flat.vmdk
-a----       08/02/2020     03:02            466 SHDrive.vmdk
```

How can I exclude the data I don't want to copy from the get-children list? In this specific case and, if possible, in "all cases" in which Get-ChildItem has to exclude an explicit content list (variable string and/or an array) in a whole file system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of PowerShell 7.3.x, the `-Exclude` and `-Include` provider parameters of cmdlets such as [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) only operate on item *names* (file / directory names, in the case of the file-system provider), not *full paths* or directory *subtrees*.

- [GitHub feature request #4126](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126) asks for *path* patterns to be supported too in the future.
- [GitHub feature request #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159) proposes a new *subtree-exclusion* parameter, such as
  `-ExcludeRecursive`.

Given that **all paths that you want to exclude are *direct children of the target directory***, I suggest a two-step approach:

```bash
# Get all files and directories in $Source, except those to be excluded.
# Note the use of \* instead of \*.*, so as to also include the
# directories (whose names don't have an extension).
$items = Get-Item $Source\* -Force | Where-Object FullName -NotIn $Ignored

# Recursively process all resulting files and directories and
# calculate their hashes.
# Note the use of -File to limit output to files.
$SourceHash = $items | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -File | Get-FileHash
```

Of course, if you define your `$Ignored` array in terms of file/directory *names* only, you *could* use `-Exclude`:

```bash
# Convert the ignore list to file/directory names only.
$Ignored = $Ignored | Split-Path -Leaf

$SourceHash = Get-ChildItem -File $Source -Recurse -Force -Exclude $Ignored |
                Get-FileHash
```

---

**If the names to exclude can occur *at any level of the subdirectory hierarchy***, more work is needed:

```bash
$ignoredRegex = '(?<=^|\{0})({1})(?=\{0}|$)' -f
                  [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar,
                  ($Ignored.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')


$SourceHash = Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse -File -Force |
                Where-Object FullName -notmatch $ignoredRegex |
                Get-FileHash
```

The above uses a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) with the (negated form of the) [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operator to exclude all specified items *and their children, recursively*, anywhere in the subdirectory tree.