# Extract the end of every lines from multiple files

Tags: powershell

I have several txt files distributed in several sub-folders.
This is what a file looks like:

```
Data file. version 01.10.

1
8
*
DAT\Trep\Typ10
DAT\Trep\Typ12
DAT\Trep\Typ13
```

what I would like to do is to extract only the part after the last "\" in order to get something like this:

```
Typ10 FileName.txt Path
Typ12 FileName.txt Path
Typ13 FileName.txt Path
...
```

I tried the following

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyData\*.txt' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_; $data=Get-Content $_}
$data = $data -replace '.*\\'
$data
```

it works well for a single file but not with several (-recurse).
Being a powershell beginner I can't figure out how to improve my script.

I also tried to add this to get the result shown above in my post, but that doesn't work either.

```
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Result list'; Expression = { $data }}, Filename, Path
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\MyData\*.txt -Recurse -File |
  Select-String '^.+\\(.+)' | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobect] @{ 
      Result = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
      FileName = $_.FileName 
      Path = $_.Path
    } 
  }
```

As for your desire to *exclude* certain folders during recursive traversal:

- Unfortunately, `Get-ChildItem -Exclude` only excludes the matching folders *themselves*, not also *their content*. There are two relevant feature requests to potentially overcome this limitation in the future:

  - [GitHub issue #4126](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126) asks for *path* patterns to be supported too in the future.
  - [GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159) proposes a new *subtree-exclusion* parameter, such as
    `-ExcludeRecursive`.
- For now, a different approach with post-filtering based on [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) is required, using folder names `Folder1` and `Folder2` as examples:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\MyData\*.txt -Recurse |
  Where-Object FullName -NotLike *\Folder1\* |
  Where-Object FullName -NotLike *\Folder2\* |
  Select-String '^.+\\(.+)' | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobect] @{ 
      Result = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
      FileName = $_.FileName 
      Path = $_.Path
    } 
  }
```

For a more flexible, cross-platform approach based on [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) matching (which is invariably more complex), see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61934592/45375).

Comment: Thanks this is perfect.
I added the following :
Out-File D:\test.csv


I noticed that the path only return D: and not D:\MyData\Folder1\SubfolderB for exemple. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Wehrmicel, I don't see this symptom, neither in Windows PowerShell (5.1) nor in PowerShell (Core) 7.3.2. What version are you running? `.Path` should definitely contain the full file path; not doing so would be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried with Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation D:\MyData\test.xls and it displays correctly now. Here is myh last question: Is there a way to exclude two folders ? I tried with -exclude Folder1, Folder2 without luck thanks again !