# Powershell move folders with exclude

Tags: powershell, except, get-childitem, file-move

I have a lots of folders with contents that I want to move to another folder
Below I want to move the 3 folders to the ARKIV folder - it works but the script crasches at the end. Am I using the Exclude flag the wrong way? If I use -Whatif it seems to want to move that folder as well - see picture 2

My code is as follows:

```
$current_logfiles = "H:\FAKTURA\"
$destination = "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV\"
$excludes = "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV\"

if ((Test-Path -Path $destination)) 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excludes  -Path H:\FAKTURA  | Move-Item  -Destination 
    H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV -Whatif
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I using the Exclude flag the wrong way?

Yes:

- `-Exclude` (like `-Include`) only operates on item (file or directory)  *names*, not *entire paths*.
- `-Excludes` only excludes the matching item *itself*. This means that when `-Recurse` is used and a *directory* is excluded, its *contents* (subtree) are *not*.

In your case, since **you're not using `-Recurse` and are therefore only targeting the *immediate child items* of your input directory**, the solution is to **use the *name only***, i.e. `$excludes = 'ARKIV'`:

```bash
$excludes = 'ARKIV'
Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excludes -Path H:\FAKTURA  | 
  Move-Item  -Destination H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV -Whatif
```

**Note**: Due to a bug in Windows PowerShell, you *must* use `-Path` in the command above, even though `-LiteralPath` is conceptually appropriate and in general more robust.

(The code could be simplified: you could use `$destination` with `-Destination` and `(Split-Path -Leaf $destination)` as the `$excludes` value.
To skip items that are already present in `$destination`, insert the following pipeline segment before `Move-Item`:
`Where-Object { -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath (Join-Path $destination $_.Name)) }`)

---

###### *Recursive* use cases currently *not* supported by `-Exclude`:

It follows from the above that, when `-Recurse` is used:

- You cannot exclude items by subtree *path*.
- You cannot exclude items *along with their subtrees*

These limitations apply to *Windows PowerShell* and to [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) up to at least the version current as of this writing, v7.3.x.
The next section links to feature requests that may provide this functionality in the future.

**Workarounds**, based on post-filtering via [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object):

In the simplest case, if the paths to exclude can be matched via [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions, use `-notlike`; e.g.:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt |
  Where-Object FullPath -notlike Arkiv/* |
  Where-Object FullPath -notlike */sub/dir/* |
```

This works for excluding the *content* of the directories of interest, but not these directories *themselves* (which isn't a problem in this example, given that `-File` is used to enumerate only *files*).

While you could add *another* `-notlike` operation that omits the `/*` in order to also match the directories themselves (e.g., `-notlike */sub/dir`), such duplication is obviously cumbersome.
An alternative is to use [*regexes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) with `-notmatch` instead:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |
  Where-Object FullPath -notmatch '(^|\\)node_modules(\\|$)'
```

- This excludes directories named `node_modules` and their subtrees wherever they may be located in the input directory subtree.
- Note that `\\` matches a verbatim `\`, i.e. a *Windows* path separator; use `/` on Unix-like platforms or `[\\/]` for cross-platform compatibility.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61934592/45375) shows a *programmatic* way to construct these regexes, based on an array of *verbatim* exclusion paths.

---

###### Potential future enhancements:

There are two relevant feature requests to potentially overcome the limitations of `-Exclude` in the future:

- [GitHub issue #4126](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126) asks for `-Exclude` to also support *path* patterns.
- [GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159) proposes a new *subtree-exclusion* parameter, such as
  `-ExcludeRecursive`.

Comment: Can you please explain this line in beginners language what is happening here? :D

Where-Object { -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath (Join-Path $destination $_.Name)) })

Comment: @HenrikRosqvist: `Join-Path $destination $_.Name` constructs a path from the destination directory and the name of the source item (directory) at hand - this is what the item's effective destination path would be if the item were to be passed to `Move-Item`. `Test-Path` tests the existence of this item destination path, i.e. returns `true` if it exists, and `$false` otherwise. `-not` negates the result of the test, and that negated result governs the behavior of `Where-Object`: in other words: only if an item with the same name does _not_ yet exist at the destination is it moved there.